# A question about the product of two solvable or nilpotent group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group.$H$ and $K$ are two proper subgroups of $G$. $H_1$ and  $K_1$ are respectively the normal subgroup of $H$ and $K$. $HK$ is a subgroup of G.

(1) please construct an example that $H_{1}K_{1}$ is a group but not a normal subgroup of $HK$ .

(2)  If $H$ is a nilpotent subgroup
and $K$ is a nilpotent normal(or non-normal) subgroup, can $HK$ not be a solvable subgroup?

(3) If $H$ and $K$ are two nilpotent normal subgroups, is $HK$ a nilpotent subgroup?

I juat proved that the product of two solvable normal subgroup is a solvable subgroup. On top of that, I have the three questions. My thought is to find these counter-examples in symmetric group.I feel that these question should be classic question.

---

Upgradation: I want to give some supplements to question 1.The following will be some results. We suppose $H$ and $K$ are proper normal subgroup of $G$. $H_1$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. $K_1$ is a normal subgroup of $K$.

(i)  $H_{1}K_{1}$ may not be a group.([The product of two normal subgroup's normal subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663508/the-product-of-two-normal-subgroups-normal-subgroup))

(ii) Even if $H_{1}K_{1}$ is a group, it may not be a normal subgroup of $HK$.(Concerning cartesian product of two groups $S_4$. This example is easy to build.)

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your efforts.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think these questions should be classic. But I don't find some results about it...

Comment: What do you mean "$H_1$ and  $K_1$ are respectively the normal group of $H$ and $K$."?

Comment: @the_fox $H_1$ is a normal subgroup of $H$. $K_1$ is a normal subgroup of  $K$.

Comment: What is a "normal group" in 2 and 3? Apart from this looking like a homework problem, you seen to have taken no trouble to make the question comprehensible.

Comment: Concerning 3, try searching for Fitting subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt alright...do you have the examples of 2 and 3...

Comment: Concerning 2, $HK/K \cong H/(H \cap K)$ and use nilpotency implies solvability. Then conclude that $HK$ *must* be solvable.

Comment: It is easy to construct examples of 1 with $K_1$ the trivial group, or examples where $H$ is a subgroup of $K$. You need more conditions to make this interesting.

Comment: @NickyHekster ...this is the same as what I proved about the sovlable subgroup... What if $K$ is not a normal subgroup...

Comment: Kegel and Wielandt proved that a finite group that is the product of two nilpotent groups is solvable. This is still an open problem for infinite groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt  thank you.

Comment: @algebraAnd.analysis An hour ago you wrote  "...this is the same as what I proved about the sovlable subgroup... What if  is not a normal subgroup..." , but then you changed the original post (inserting (or non-normal)). You should not do that. In addition, better split 3 questions over 3 posts. And show some of your own efforts: you claimed that you proved something (*"is the same as what I proved about the sovlable subgroup"*), then show it!

Comment: @NickyHekster Sorry, I will do it next time.