# The product of two normal subgroup's normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation

**If $A$ and $B$ are normal subgroups of group $G$, is the product of the normal subgroup $A_1$ of $A$ and the normal subgroup $B_1$ of $B$ a group?**

I have tried to find the example in symmetric group($S_4$, $S_5$,$S_6$ and $S_7$) and generalized qaternion group($Q_{2^{n}} $$= \langle a, b \mid a^{2^{n-1}}=1, b^{2}=a^{2^{n-2}},$$b^{-1}ab$$=a^{-1} \rangle$). I also tried some special groups. But there does not seem to have example in group like the above.  Thus, I was wondering what conditions a group $G$ needs can make sure evey product of  $A_1$ and $B_1$ like the upfront is a subgroup.

Comment: There are some composing problems...I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Alright, the type setting prolem has been solved.

Comment: What do you mean by product? $A_1B_1 = \{ab : a \in A_1, b \in B_1\}$?

Comment: @healynr Yes, it is.╮(‵▽′)╭

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the product $HI$ of two subgroups $H,I$ of $G$ need *not* be a subgroup of $G$ if neither $H$ nor $I$ is a normal subgroup. We also know that if $A_1 \trianglelefteq A \trianglelefteq G$, then it is *not* necessarily true that $A_1 \trianglelefteq G$. So, it is possible that neither $A_1$, $B_1$ are normal in $G$.

Consider the Dihedral group of order $8$. 
$$D_8=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,x,ax,a^2x,a^3x\}$$
Two of its subgroups are $X=\{e,x, a^2, a^2x\}$ and $Y=\{e,ax,a^2,a^3x\}$ both of which are normal (and isomorphic to Klein $4$ group ($V_4$)).

Also, note $\{e,x\} \trianglelefteq X$ and $\{e,ax\} \trianglelefteq Y$ since all subgroups of $V_4$ are normal in $V_4$. However, 
$$\{e,x\}\{e,ax\}=\{e,x,ax,a^3\}$$
is *not* a subgroup of $D_8$, for $(ax)(a^3)=a^2x$ is not in the set. You can verify all of these by noting the operations of $D_8$ online; [this page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D8) has a good outline of the structure of $D_8$.

So we have shown an example of the product of two normal subgroups of two other normal subgroups of $G$ that is not itself a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Can you construct an example? I think so, But I want an example.

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis See my edit.

Comment: Thank you. I ever wanted to try Dihedral group, but I didn't. This group is very similar with generalized qaternion group. After that group, I have no confidence...However, the example should be in the dihedral group.....=͟͟͞͞(꒪ᗜ꒪ ‧̣̥̇)(≖_≖ )....